# How to declare dependency on native .so library for tests?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have a production application in Akka that I start with the following option:

```
-Djava.library.path="./native/"
```

(with `native` directory containing a library `libsigar-amd64-linux.so`) and everything is fine.

When I type `sbt test` I'm facing the following error:

```
[executorTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-13] DEBUG Sigar  - no libsigar-amd64-linux.so in java.library.path
org.hyperic.sigar.SigarException: no libsigar-amd64-linux.so in java.library.path
```

I tried to modify `build.sbt` with:

```
libraryDependencies in Test ++= file("native/libsigar-amd64-linux.so")
```

but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM will only load libraries from the `java.library.path`. The `libraryDependencies` is for declaring managed dependencies (as e.g. jars).

```
> help libraryDependencies
Declares managed dependencies.
```

What you need is to specify the aforementioned `java.library.path` for your tests. You have two choices.

One you can run tests in a forked JVM, add following lines to your `build.sbt`

```
javaOptions in Test += s"""-Djava.library.path=${baseDirectory.value / ".native"}"""

fork in Test := true
```

Second you can run sbt using (note this will override the `java.library.path` for the whole process), which in case you're not forking tests, will be visible in tests

```
sbt -Djava.library.path=./native
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run with forked tests you need to pass the `-Djava.library.path` to the jvm that runs the tests, you can do that in your sbt-config with something like this:

```
javaOptions in Test += "-Djava.library.path=\"./native/\""
```

If you do not run with forked tests, the tests is run inside the sbt-jvm and you need to pass `-Djava.library.path` to that jvm, using the `SBT_OPTS` environment variable for example.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this doesn't work. I have to use 'sbt test' command so I can connect it to jenkins.

Comment: Which of the options does not work, javaOptions and forked tests or passing parameter to sbt jvm?