# Add a .so library with class files to sbt scala project

Tags: scala, sbt, swig, .so

I need to call some c functions from my sbt project. I have already used SWIG and created a .so file along with .class files.

I wrapped everything in a jar file and put it in lib/ folder but it keeps saying no value found.

How can I use the .so library generated from swig along with the .classes files in an sbt project?

The name of the library is `libsample.so`.

I can successfully upload the library in sbt with `System.LoadLibrary("sample")` but I cannot call `sample.entry()` (not found value sample...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare dependency on native .so library for tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385458/how-to-declare-dependency-on-native-so-library-for-tests)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error. You say you cannot "call sample.entry()". Is that a compiler error from Scala or a runtime error? The former suggests that your (non-native) .class files are not on the class path.

Comment: I get the error when running sbt , the command is "sbt run-main .....". I did put the .class files in a jar file and put it in the /lib folder. But the .scala file cannot see it. I was told that everything we put in the /lib folder of an sbt project is put automatically on the classpath. but it is not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like a DependencyWalker and make sure your are not missing any dependencies on they box?

Comment: This is the problem I am facing. I am using sbt scala and I can successfully load the .so library. But it just happened that this .so library depends on some other .class files that I also added to the /lib folder. But the existing scala files seem not to see those external .class files